# VBA Filter Partial String Containing Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, filter, partial

I need to filter Col A based on a PARTIAL STRING.

The user needs to be able to filter for YEAR only ... or YEAR & MONTH ... or YEAR & MONTH & DAY

YEAR ONLY : 20
YEAR & MONTH : 2002
YEAR & MONTH & DAY : 200206

The following will filter the year or the year & month .... it fails to filter for year / month / day.

Thank you for looking.

```
Sub FiltDate()

Dim strName As String
Dim range_to_filter As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set range_to_filter = Range("A2:A500000")   'Sheet4.

Dim ret As String
Dim prompt As String

prompt = "Enter DATE" & vbCrLf & _
"For YEAR ONLY: YY" & vbCrLf & _
"For YEAR & MONTH: YYMM" & vbCrLf & _
"For YEAR & MONTH & DAY: YYMMDD"

ret = InputBox$(prompt)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myYear As String, myMonth As String, myDay As String, myDate1 As Long, 
mydate2
If Len(ret) > 1 Then
    myYear = Left$(ret, 2)
    On Error Resume Next
    myMonth = Mid$(ret, 3, 2)
    myDay = Mid$(ret, 5, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If myDay <> "" Then
        myDate1 = myYear & myMonth & myDay
        mydate2 = myYear & myMonth & myDay + 1
    ElseIf myMonth <> "" Then
        myDate1 = myYear & myMonth & "01"
        mydate2 = myYear & myMonth & "32"
    Else
        myDate1 = myYear & "0101"
        mydate2 = myYear + 1 & "0101"
    End If
    Range("A2:A500000").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & myDate1 & String(3, "0"), 1, "<" 
& mydate2 & String(3, "0")
End If
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Download Workbook](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/oB2st0bfHM6fl5BKbleFiWlLcK3xEyZnXPZ8CoiN8TN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am talking about.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResetFilters()
    Dim Wks As Worksheet
    Set Wks = Sheets("Call Log File")
    With Wks
        On Error Resume Next
        If Wks.AutoFilterMode Then
            Wks.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub FiltDate()

Dim strName As String
Dim range_to_filter As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set range_to_filter = Range("A2:A500000")   'Sheet4.

Dim ret As String
Dim prompt As String

prompt = "Enter DATE" & vbCrLf & _
    "For YEAR ONLY: YY" & vbCrLf & _
    "For YEAR & MONTH: YYMM" & vbCrLf & _
    "For YEAR & MONTH & DAY: YYMMDD"

ret = InputBox$(prompt)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim myYear As String, myMonth As String, myDay As String, myDate1 As Long, mydate2 As Long
    If Len(ret) > 1 Then
        myYear = Left$(ret, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        myMonth = Mid$(ret, 3, 2)
        myDay = Mid$(ret, 5, 2)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If myDay <> "" Then
        'format to YYMMDDxxx or 9 digit number
        'need more errorchecking because cint("text") will give error
            myDate1 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + CInt(myMonth) * 100000 + CInt(myDay) * 1000
            mydate2 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + CInt(myMonth) * 100000 + CInt(myDay) * 1000 + 1000
        ElseIf myMonth <> "" Then
            myDate1 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + CInt(myMonth) * 100000 + 1000
            mydate2 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + CInt(myMonth) * 100000 + 1000 + 32000
        Else
            myDate1 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + 100000 + 1000
            mydate2 = CInt(myYear) * 10000000 + 10000000 + 100000 + 1000
        End If
        MsgBox "mydate1=" & myDate1, vbOKOnly
        MsgBox "mydate2=" & mydate2, vbOKOnly
        'Range("A2:A500000").AutoFilter 1, ">=" & myDate1, 1, "<" & mydate2  - cleaned this up
        range_to_filter.AutoFilter 1, ">=" & myDate1, 1, "<" & mydate2
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to give you credit for this answer  .. like other forums ? If so .. how ?

Comment: Yes, mark it as answered by clicking the up arrow above the score for my answer.  You can also click the up arrow beside any comment showing that the comment adds value to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts that you have formatted your filter as a string and your data in A2:A500000 is number.  The code then adds strings to a variable that you have defined as LONG. The first two function like you'd hope just by luck.  The problem with the day is that if your prompted string value is 200101 then you would expect

```
myDay = "01"
```

and after this code:

```
mydate2 = myYear & myMonth & myDay + 1
```

it will be considered as "01" + 1 = 2 since vba will change your string to a value automatically.  Thus `mydate2` = 20012 instead of the intended 200102.  You cannot +1 a text value.

Try changing everything to integer and adding 1000 for each day (since you have 3 extra digits after), or you will have to come up with some logic like the way you handled the month.

I also noticed that you also should define the variable `mydate2` in the following:

```
Dim myYear As String, myMonth As String, myDay As String, myDate1 As Long, mydate2
```

Comment: @Jerry, please post responses as a comment below my answer.  At this time I cannot comment on questions or other persons answers due to not enough reputation.

Comment: I wanted to but didn't see a way to show the code in a formatted manner. Should I just attach new code as a download or ????   I am not very familiar with this forum.

Comment: I went through the code and changed every thing that was a STRING to an INTEGER (if VBA would accept it) or to LONG (if VBA would not accept INTEGER).  That didn't work.  ??

Comment: The code that was up for a short period time showed that you formatted them as integer but you were adding strings to those variables.   That also will not work.  If you go down this path of integers and your numbers are in the format as YYMMDDXXX you will have to add 1000 for each day and 1,000,000 for each month.  Then you will be working with integers.

Comment: "If you go down this path of integers and your numbers are in the format as YYMMDDXXX you will have to add 1000 for each day and 1,000,000 for each month."   Sorry ... you lost me.

Comment: Sorry, if you accidentally press enter it will send the comment and it cannot be edited for 5 minutes after.  All you can do is delete and re-enter.  I have posted an answer with the amended code.  You will need to work on error checking and feel free to take out the MsgBox entries.   Please mark as answered.